# Using streamlit to build question/answer app with history

Tags: python, streamlit

It is quite simple to build a question / answer app using streamlit, but ideally id like to be able to allow the user to keep asking questions and continue showing the previous questions / answers. Instead of the behavior of reusing the same box to ask new questions.

The problem is that I can't use a while loop in streamlit as it runs all the code on load. I tried creating a `button` that when clicked triggered the "ask" code with a unique counter passed into the `streamlit.text_input` call, but it isn't working as id hoped.

Is there a way to do this using streamlit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of each message in the conversation using [Streamlit Session State](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/session-state). This is a small example from the linked tutorial, to give you an idea of how it works.

```python
import streamlit as st

st.title('Counter Example using Callbacks')
if 'count' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.count = 0

def increment_counter():
    st.session_state.count += 1

st.button('Increment', on_click=increment_counter)

st.write('Count = ', st.session_state.count)
```

To create your QA app, you can use Streamlit [chat elements](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/chat), they even created [a very cool tutorial to build conversational apps using LLMs](https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/tutorials/build-conversational-apps), quite similar to what you want to achieve.